# Removing values in textfiles on python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have the current example.txt file that contains the following names:

```
Names
Max
Alex
Rob
```

**Task: How do you remove one name from the text file?**

Comment: Please post the code you already tried

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem, here is a quick solution. Before posting makes sure you try different code.

In this example, I use an input file and output file (2 files to do it).

```
infile = "file1.txt"
outfile = "file2.txt"

delete_list = ["Alex"]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
   for word in delete_list:
     line = line.replace(word, "")
   fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```